# How create a switcher from responsive version of my site to Desktop version?

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design

I want create a button like "view Desktop site" that switch to desktop format site.
I'm using CSS @media for a responsive desing and my site is in HTML/PHP.
And Can someone say me why the "request desktop site" of browser app doesn't run?

Comment: Have you got any code that you can share?

Comment: The user can usually do this anyway; for instance safari and chrome offer an option to request the desktop site from a menu in their respective apps.

Comment: I have just notice that "request desktop site" of browser app doesn't run.
someone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to use a parameter in your url:

```
<a href="sitename.html/?desktop">See desktop site</a>
```

And then have PHP code thus, in your `head`:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['desktop'] {
        echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='mobile.css'>";
    }
?>
```

This would mean that only if the parameter `desktop` in the url was **not** set to true, your site will appear responsive. This will only work for as long as the `?desktop parameter is set, though.

---

Alternatively, if you didn't want to set a cookie because of returning to the site later, you could use a PHP session. If `$_GET['desktop']` is set on one page, it will continue for rest of your site until either you (`session_destroy()`) or the user (quitting the browser) ends the session

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['desktop']) { 
         start_session();
         $_SESSION['desktop'] = true;
         exit();
    }
?>
```

Then in your `<head>`:

```
<?php
    start_session(); /* Only if on a different page */
        if ($_SESSION['desktop'] {
             echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='mobile.css'>";
        }
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: It's a bad idea beacause when The user, for example, change page ang go to "contact us" the link'll reset and the pag returns to mobile mode

Comment: Good point, then I would set a cookie, I will update my answer now

Comment: There is another problem beacause if the user exit and he'll return in the site later the cookie show him a desktop site then I think that use "request desktop site" of diferent browser app is the best way for control responsive desing but I have noticed that in my site this function doesn't run. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little JavaScript plugin that can do it for you:

http://filzhut.net/projects/responsive-switch/

Once included, it's just a simple link:

```
<a href="#"
  class="rs-link"
  data-link-desktop="Switch to desktop version"
  data-link-responsive="Switch to responsive / mobile version"
  data-always-visible="false">
</a>
```

Comment: I have just tryed that code but it don't run for me beacuse if I use it the site will became desktop site and it doesn't change at click